# Allowing Host notification pop ups in guest Virtualbox session that is full screen

Tags: windows, ubuntu, popup, virtualbox

I am running Virtualbox on a Windows 7 host with an Ubuntu guest.

I like to have my virtual box full screen for screen real estate purposes. However, I have an outlook instance open on the host, where I can only get access to my mail through that. I seem to miss emails sometimes if I don't check back on my host every once and a while.

So I was wondering if anyone knows if there is a way to **allow** notification pop-ups like Windows outlook new mail notifications to pop up over my full screen. 
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Pretty sure VirtualBox is designed to prevent that. You could use an email client in Ubuntu to either check that mailbox or have Outlook forward emails (or just specific emails) to an email account set up in a client in Ubuntu. You don't even need a GUI for that.  Another alternative is to have Outlook play a sound when an email comes in.

Comment: Oh yeah I guess the other thing was that I needed to have a physical ID card to access the mail but if I passed it through to VB then it locked my computer. It doesn't really matter to me anymore since I'm not there anymore though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone who has to use VB at work a lot one solution I found was to make the virtual box window huge and hiding the task bar beneath my real one. this does come with the one negative of having to hide your task bar but anything you need from it can still be accessed from the windows key. however since VirtualBox isn't technically fullscreen it doesn't block your notifications. or just have outlook for your phone but I know that isn't always the best solution.

Edit, I didn't realize ubuntu was the OS you were running on in VB, that being said there are hotkeys that work just as well and if memory serves me well alt f1 does the same thing as the windows key but for ubuntu.